# How can I restrict file type for the the wagtail.documents.blocks.DocumentChooserBlock?

Tags: django, wagtail

So I would like to restrict the type of file that an admin can choose to upload to the CMS using the `wagtail.documents.blocks.DocumentChooserBlock`. I can't seem to find any documentation anywhere. This is the most I have found http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0/topics/streamfield.html#documentchooserblock.

I looked through the code to see if they render an input field perhaps. But its a button.

```
<button type="button" class="button action-choose button-small button-secondary">Choose a document</button>
```

That opens a chooser model that selects previously uploaded documents or upload a new one.

I have also looked to find the template files for the chooser. But I have not been able to find where that input is located. It seems like a lot of work to override the chooser template.

Here I am adding the DocumentChooserBlock.

```
class IndicatorWidgetsBlock(blocks.StreamBlock):
    flourish = blocks.StructBlock(
        [
            ('label', blocks.CharBlock(required=False,
                                       help_text="This widget's tab label on the indicator")),
            ('title', blocks.CharBlock(required=True)),
            ('hide_title', blocks.BooleanBlock(default=False, required=False)),
            ('html_file', DocumentChooserBlock(required=True)),
            ('sdg', blocks.ChoiceBlock(required=False, choices=sdg_choices,
                                       label='SDG Goal')),
            ('source', blocks.RichTextBlock(
                features=['link'], required=False)),
        ],
        icon='code',
        template='takwimu/_includes/dataview/code.html'
    )
    class Meta:
        icon = 'form'
```

I want to restrict the type of file uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

I would try raising a validation error during the .save() method. This would allow you to prevent the action and redirect a user to choose the correct file format.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping for some  `accept="..."` type of thing

Comment: If you wanted to edit the html to insert a accept attribute on the html, there is a way. It's not recommended though. Here's the article from w3 that gives the warning.  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp.